# Actor-critic architecture: How is the policy updated?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am going through the [ddpg baseline code](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/ddpg/ddpg.py) to try and gain an intuitive understanding of how the actor and critic networks function.

DDPG has two components: the actor which is the deterministic policy `\pi` and the critic which is the state-value function `Q(s, a)`. The way you update the actor `\pi` is by computing the gradient of `Q(s, \pi(s))`. The idea is that the policy can be seen as a continuous equivalent of `argmax` and so you try to update it such as it takes the action that maximizes the Q-function in a given state.

This can be depicted as shown below.

[image]

The code shows three different neural networks created.

1. `actor_tf = create_neural_net(observations) # Maps states to desired actions`
2. `critic_tf = create_neural_net(observations, actions) # Updates value function`
3. `critic_with_actor_tf = create_neural_net(observations, actor_tf) # Used for policy updating`

My question is with how the policy is updated, and more specifically with `critic_with_actor_tf`.

As explained [here](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/551),

So critic_with_actor_tf represents `Q(s,\pi(s))` the action-state value in a state `s` (here `observation = state`) following the policy `pi` (the actor) (`a = \pi(s)`). This is what is used to compute the gradient for the actor:

```
 self.actor_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(self.critic_with_actor_tf)
```

So, it seems like the actor updated by reducing the mean of `critic_with_actor_tf`.

This raises the question, what does the **TD Error** shown in the diagram above represent and how is *that* related to updating the policy?

Comment: Partial answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64501/trouble-understanding-the-partial-differentiation-used-in-reinforcement-learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TD Error is used to directly update the critic and not the actor.

The actor is updated in the direction of the critic using:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial l}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial Q(s, a, w)}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial u}
\end{equation}

Follow up question about what this equation really means [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64501/trouble-understanding-the-partial-differentiation-used-in-reinforcement-learning).

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two problems on your hand:

1. learning the Q-function
2. learning the policy

The Q-functions tells you how rewarding an action $a$ would be in state $s$. Once you take the action $a$ and transition from state $s$ to $s'$, you are rewarded $r$ right away. How rewarding it was to take the action $a$ in $s$ is the sum of the received reward $r$ and the Q-value of the state that you end up in, hence you want to minimize

$$r + Q(s', a', w) - Q(s, a, w)$$

where $w$ are the parameters of the function approximator and $a'$ the action you would take in the following state $s'$. This is the TD Error and mimimizing it will learn the Q-function.

So, the TD Error is used to learn the Q-function, basically the same way as it is done in plain-vanilla (Deep) Q-Learning. But while in plain-vanilla (Deep) Q-learning you would base the actor's policy on the Q-function entirely (plus some randomness to not get stuck), in the actor-critic context the Q-function is just a means to the end of training the policy itself. For this reason, the learned Q-function then serves as an optimization objective for the policy by learning the policy parameters $u$ such that it outputs the action $a$ which maximizes $Q(s,a,w)$ (see your [other question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64501/trouble-understanding-the-partial-differentiation-used-in-reinforcement-learning)). The chain rule pops up in that context, because you are not trying to do regression by minimizing some error, but rather you are trying to maximize $Q$ with respect to one of its arguments.